# Codeigniter 4 API with Angular : 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: php, angular, api, cors, codeigniter-4

Honestly, I've been struggling and trying every solution to overcome this issue caused by the Codeigniter API controller but unfortunately still not solved yet.

So using angular and whenever I try to call this API: http://afma-cloud-api.synchronism.com/api/

I got CORS Error on the console saying :

```
  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://afma-cloud-api.synchronism.com/api/' from origin 
'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I've Tried many solutions Like adding headers in the htaccess file using the code below :

```
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Also, I tried to set the headers directly in every part on my PHP code but nothing changed.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
```

And finally here's my controller code :

```
namespace App\Controllers;



use App\Models\ApiModel;
use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;
use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\Response;


class Api extends BaseController
{

    protected $apiModel;
    protected $apiConfig;
    protected $curl;
    protected $pipelines;
    protected $tickets;
    protected $allTickets;
    protected $stages;

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->apiConfig = new \Config\ApiConfig();
        $this->apiModel = new ApiModel();
        $this->curl = \Config\Services::curlrequest();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->response->setJSON( ['message' => 'Interne Api used For Afma Cloud'] );
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show request snapshot and the _response_ headers?

Comment: Thank you, for your interest but everything seemed correctly using postman headers send status 200, and cross-origin / methods were allowed but nothing worked until I had to set the header status before sending the JSON dataset.

Answer (score -1):

Fiiiiinnaly found it, after much research, I figured out that I had to set the headers status to 200, and voila it worked like a charm.

```
For native PHP I used this : header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

***For Codeigniter HTTP response service I used this :***

```
$this->response->setStatusCode(200);
$this->response->setStatusCode(200)->setJSON( ['message' => 'Interne Api used For Afma Cloud'] );
```